# Addition law for non mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

The addition law for non mutually exclusive events is given in my textbook as

> $P(A \space \text{or} \space B)=P(A \space\cup \space B)= P(A)+P(B)-P(A \space \cap \space B)$

I understand the logic behind this and would be fine if it were written as $P(A \space \text{or} \space B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \space \cap \space B)$ however I am fairly certain that in this case it is incorrect to say that $P(A \space \text{or} \space B)=P(A \space\cup \space B)$

Here is a diagram to further elaborate [image: A union B]

From the diagram would it not be true that $P(A \space \cup \space B)=P(A \space \text{or} \space B) + P(A \space \text{and} \space B)$?

Is there a mistake in my textbook or am I missing something crucial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context “A or B” means “A, or B, or both”. So it is correct to say that $P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A \cup B)$. There’s no mistake in your textbook.

Comment: If that is the case then why have they subtracted the $P(A \space \cap B)$ term , would $P(A \space \cap B)$ not qualify as both A,B?

Comment: Because if you just add P(A) and P(B), you’ll be counting the intersection area twice. You have to subtract one of the two copies.

Comment: Forget about probabilities for a minute — just think about areas.

Comment: Area of overall figure-eight = area of A + area of B - area of overlap.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise...

$$P(x \in A ~\text{or}~ x \in B) = P(x \in (A \cup B)).$$

Bonus:

$$P(x \in A ~\text{and}~ x \in B) = P(x \in (A \cap B)).$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems by the definition that when they talk about $P(A\text{ or }B)$ they actually mean $P(\text{at least }A\text{ or }B)$, that is $P(A,B\text{ or }A\text{ and }B$)

Comment: Yes, "or" is used in the inclusive sense.  Exclusive or can be written "xor".  So A xor B means A or B but not both.